# Intel Atom Asus Eee PC - overclock not working

Tags: xubuntu, intel, atom, tlp

so I got this old netbook from a friend and she wants me to make it usable. I installed Xubuntu but it seems that this ESH settings in BIOS which should overclock CPU  up to 30% does not work! When I do cat /proc/cpuinfo|grep MHz I still see numbers around 1300 and not 1.74GHz as I hoped even when CPU load is high.
I installed this TLP package (http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/improve-power-usage-battery-life-in.html) thinking that this is necessary to make ESH work, but still it's the same.
If I run *sudo tlp-stat* -p I get

```
--- TLP 1.1 --------------------------------------------

+++ Processor
CPU model = Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU Z520 @ 1.33GHz

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver = acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor = ondemand
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil 
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq = 800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq = 1333000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies = 1333000 1067000 800000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_driver = acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_governor = ondemand
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil 
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq = 800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq = 1333000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies = 1333000 1067000 800000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/boost = (not available)

x86_energy_perf_policy: program not installed.

/sys/module/workqueue/parameters/power_efficient = Y
/proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog = 0
```

Isn't this boost (not available) the problem? Any ideas how to make this CPU work faster? Youtube is unwatchable even at frikin 360p unfortunately  like this :-\

What if I just put some number to scaling_max_freq into TLP config /etc/default/tlp? Can I just put there any number of MHz, would it take it?

```
sudo lshw -class display
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: System Controller Hub (SCH Poulsbo) Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0

glxinfo | grep -i "vendor\|rendering"
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
    Vendor: VMware, Inc. (0xffffffff)
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.

       version: 07
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=gma500 latency=0
       resources: irq:22 memory:f3f80000-f3ffffff ioport:c880(size=8) memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:f3f40000-f3f7ffff memory:c0000-dffff

lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display' 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation System Controller Hub (SCH Poulsbo) Graphics Controller (rev 07)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. System Controller Hub (SCH Poulsbo) Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: gma500
    Kernel modules: gma500_gfx
```

Comment: if you are having issue with video quality, you might need different video drivers... can you post output of "sudo lshw -class display"

Comment: it's not video quality, but videos are super choppy. Like 2fps. Disabling VP9 codec via h264ify FF extension does not seem to help

Comment: I only ask about video drivers because your laptop sounds faster than my Raspberry Pi, which plays video just fine. what do you get from: glxinfo | grep -i "vendor\|rendering"

Comment: this command might also give useful info: lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'

Comment: If a BIOS setting doesn't work, it might be a BIOS problem, unrelated to Ubuntu. That said, even if you could overclock it, it would have done nothing to make the netbook usable. Intel's GMA500 is a well known piece of hardware that doesn't have a proper Linux driver, and Intel can't be bothered to provide one. Basically, that machine is only good as a server.

Comment: I added those commands outputs to the post

Comment: so looks like it's not possible? I changed this value scaling_max_freq as I wrote but to no effect :-\